# How to get two Chromium source-code checkouts to the same revision?

Tags: version-control, chromium

I have an older checkout of Chromium on which I have done some work. I'm trying to use glient to get a checkout I have on a different machine to the same revision as the former.

However, I can't find a good way to get my current revision using gclient. `gclient revinfo` outputs revision info mapping for the client and its dependencies, which I don't really get how I could use to sync to a revision.

If you have experience with gclient, please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

To update to a specific revision, use

> gclient sync --revision src@####

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Comment: In order to find my revision I type `gclient revinfo` and that gives me a whole bunch of different revision numbers for several sub-directories. Which one do I chose for `gclient sync --revision` and in what order?